# Connecting React App to SmartContract

Tags: react

I have an application with next.js, in which I have integrated Metamask with the web3-react library.
Now I want to connect my application with my contract (I have used truffle).
But I'm a bit lost, I'm not clear which library I have to use to interact, and if it's better to use libraries like typechain or truffle-contract instead of using the ABI directly.
If someone can clarify.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Drizzle would be a good choice for interacting with smart contracts. https://www.trufflesuite.com/drizzle
Do explore drizzle react component as well https://github.com/trufflesuite/drizzle/blob/develop/packages/react-components/README.md

A sample code would look like

```
const response = await drizzle.contracts["MyTokenContract"].methods["transfer"]('ox1111111',100)
.send({from:drizzleState.accounts[0]});
```